# Is there theory about complexity conservation of number?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any one-to-one correspondence $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, small numbers mostly corresponds to small numbers and big numbers mostly corresponds to big numbers, intuitively. And in fact, limit of the function $f$ diverges to $\infty$.

Similarly, for any one-to-one correspondence $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, there is correspondence like "small to small, big to big", too. (It may be because $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$?) Small natural number mostly corresponds to integer that has small absolute value. Big natural number mostly corresponds to integer that has big absolute value. And limit of the function $|f|$ diverges to $\infty$.

It is able to think about $\mathbb{Q}$ similarly. Small natural number mostly corresponds to rational number that have low complexity of ratio.(Have small denominator and numerator when expressed in irreducible fraction form) Big natural number mostly corresponds to rational number that have high complexity of ratio.

It looks like that one-to-one correspondence conserves complexity of number. I think it may be able to measure absolute(?) complexity of number, from this complexity conservation.

What I wrote up to here is too abstract and just intuitive-based so I want to find some accurate theory or theorem about those subjects. Can you suggest where should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one notion of "complexity" you might be looking for refers to *ordered sets*.
What you are actually saying, is that if we have a bijection between two ordinals, then $|f|\rightarrow\infty$, where in $|f|$ I refer to the ordinal representing the element $|f|$, and in $\infty$ I refer to the ordinal of the set $f$ is working on.

This claim is indeed true in general, for any linear order you may put on a set. Of course every linear order will induce different notion of "complexity", but I think this is basically the direction you should go at. If you can provide further details about things you've tried, or some examples, I can try to assist further.

Useful links -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order